# ZendFramework Form: Change select to input type text if verification fails

Tags: forms, zend-framework

EDIT: Okay, I've stripped this down to the bare minimum.

The below code is how I would set up what I'm trying to accomplish in straight html/php.

If the form has been submitted and the verification of fields does not pass, a text field appears, otherwise, if the form has NOT been submitted, a dropdown is offered.

html/php:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="state">
      <?php
          if(!$_POST['submit']){
              // show the select list of states.
              echo '<select name="state">
                      <option>list of all states</option>
                    </select>';
          }else{
              // show text input box
              echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_POST['select'].'" name="state" />';
          }
      ?>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

But I have no clue how I would set this up with the ZendFramework Forms Class, or how to tap into it to even begin to do this.

Comment: To me it is completely unclear what you are asking. Can you show some code and explain more clearly what you're trying to do, please.

Comment: @markus, added some code to try and explain what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **really** should not do this kind of stuff (I mean write plain-text form) if you're using Zend Framework. You should use the built-in methods.

First of all, enable the Form and create a form. Then use this very-easy-to-understand code. Note that I've not tried if it works 100% but this is 100% the logic you need.

**Form class**

```
class Application_Form_YourFormName extends Zend_Form
{
   public function init()
   {

      $this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);
      $this->setAction('THE-URL-WHERE-THIS-FORM-IS-MANAGED');

      $Element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('state');
      $Element->setLabel('State:');
      $Element->addValidators(array(/*DON'T KNOW WHAT KIND OF VALIDATION YOU NEED*/));
      $Element->addFilters(array(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim(),
          new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities(array('quotestyle' => ENT_QUOTES))));
      $Element->setRequired();
      $this->addElement($Element);
      unset($Element);

      $this->addElement('reset', 'Reset');
      $this->addElement('submit', 'Submit');
   }

   public function stateNotPresent()
   {
      $this->removeElement('state');

      // Note that getStates() is an hypotetical method of an
      // hypotetical Application_Model_State where you can retrieve an
      // array containing the list of the state you have. This array is
      // needed to fill the Select list.
      $States = Application_Model_State::getStates();
      $Element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('statelist');
      $Element->setLabel('State:');
      $Element->setMultiOptions($States);
      $Element->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_InArray($States));
      $Element->setRequired();
      $Element->setOrder($this->count() - 2);
      $this->addElement($Element);
      unset($Element);
   }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
public function name-of-the-action-you-needAction()
{
   $Form = new Application_Form_YourFormName();
   if ($this->_request->isPost())
   {
      if ($Form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
      {
         // Do things. A good text has been entered
      }
      else
      {
         $Form->stateNotPresent();
         if ($Form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
         {
            // Do things. A good selection has been entered.
         }
         else
         {
            // echo the edited form (the one with the dropdown list)
            $this->view->Form = $Form;
         }      
      }
   }
   // The first time the page is requested.
   // The page with the text box will be printed
   else
      $this->view->Form = $Form;
}
```

**VIEW-OF-THE-ACTION.phtml**

```
if ($this->Form != null)
   echo $this->Form;
```

I hope you'll appreciate the effort I made to let you understand.